# I set "height" CSS property in percent (%) for div element but html render nothing. Can any one help me?

Tags: html, css

I set "height" CSS property in percent (%) for div element but html render noting. But if  I set "height" CSS property  in length values, like px, cm, etc it works. Can any one help me?

```
   <html>  
        <head>  
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  
        </head>  
        <body>  
        <div style="width: 40%; height: 40%; background-color: #565;  ">  
        </div>  
        </body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to set html, body width and height to 100%, so set them in your stylesheet like that

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

after that your problem will be solved

Answer (score 1):

Try using this...

```
width: 40vw;
height: 40vh;
```